# What earthly events marks the end of Satya and Treta Yuga?

Tags: history

The end of Dwapara Yuga is easy to find, which is the end of Shree Krishna avatara. But the others, I cannot find any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two earthly events happened at the end of Satya Yuga. The first one with Raja Harishchandra's rule & the second one with Ajapala's rule on current 28th Mahayuga. [This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626846.html) of Skanda Purana mentiones goddess Bhairavi was called as Ajapaleshvari by this king.

The end of Treta Yuga happened with the end of lord rama avatara. [This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371757.html) from the same Purana mentioned that.

Comment: Was Raja Harishchandra involved in any big conflict, like Lord Rama or Shree Krishna?

Comment: yes, there are tales that depicts that he never lied. Read about him here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harishchandra

Comment: You should cite some sources/references.

Answer (score 1):

The end of Treta yuga and beginning of Dwapar included several unpleasant and inauspicious phenomenon (earthly and otherwise) as mentioned in this [section](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a140.htm) of Santi Parva, Mahabharata

> Towards the end of Treta and the beginning of Dwapara, a frightful drought occurred, extending over twelve years, in consequence of what the gods had ordained. At that time which was the end of Treta and the commencement of Dwapara, when the period came for many creatures superannuated by age to lay down their lives, the thousand-eyed deity of heaven poured no rain. The planet Vrihaspati began to move in a retrograde course, and Soma abandoning his own orbit, receded towards the south. Not even could a dew-drop be seen, what need then be said of clouds gathering together? The rivers all shrank into narrow streamlets. Everywhere lakes and wells and springs disappeared and lost their beauty in consequence of that order of things which the gods brought about. Water having become scarce, the places set up by charity for its distribution became desolate. 1 The Brahmanas abstained from sacrifices and recitation of the Vedas. They no longer uttered Vashats and performed other propitiatory rites. Agriculture and keep of cattle were given up. Markets and shops were abandoned. Stakes for tethering sacrificial animals disappeared. People no longer collected diverse kinds of articles for sacrifices. All festivals and amusements perished. Everywhere heaps of bones were visible and every place resounded with the shrill cries and yells of fierce creatures. 2 The cities and towns of the earth became empty of inhabitants. Villages and hamlets were burnt down. Some afflicted by robbers, some by weapons, and some by bad kings, and in fear of one another, began to fly away. Temples and places of worship became desolate. They that were aged were forcibly turned out of their houses. Kine and goats and sheep and buffaloes fought (for food) and perished in large numbers. The Brahmanas began to die on all sides. Protection was at an end. Herbs and plants were dried up. The earth became shorn of all her beauty and exceedingly awful like the trees in a crematorium. In that period of terror, when righteousness was nowhere, O Yudhishthira, men in hunger lost their senses and began to eat one another. The very Rishis, giving up their vows and abandoning their fires and deities, and deserting their retreats in woods, began to wander hither and thither (in search of food)